# Style with text freezes Openlayers react / capacitor app on IOS after unlock (

Tags: reactjs, openlayers, use-effect, freeze

I'm writing a cross-plattform react application with capacitor and facing freezes in the IOS application (IOS version 15.3.1 - also occured on lower versions) when adding features to OpenLayers ("ol": "^6.3.1"). The features are added in multiple useEffect hooks to the map component (source.addFeature(…)).

The problem arises when I close the app, keep it laying for around 5 seconds and then reopen it. Or if I shortly lock the screen and unlock it again.

After some time, between 10 seconds and 2 minutes, the app manages to recover. After the app has recovered it continues running as if nothing happend.
If I debug the app in Xcode and touch the frozen app user interface I get the following console output: App[449:19368][IPC] Connection::waitForSyncReply: Timed-out while waiting for reply for WebPage_touchEventSync from process 451, id=39

The freeze appears independent of the used style for the feature (replaced all images with an inline CircleStyle). If I'm not adding any features the application doesn't freeze!

I found out that the application only freezes when I apply a text to my feature style. If I replace the **text** the application won't freeze

```
new Style({
    image: new Icon({
      opacity: 1,
      src: imageSrc,
      anchor: [0.5, 1],
      scale: 0.6
    }),
    text: new Text({
      text: "This text breaks my app",
      fill: new Fill({
        color: textColor
      }),
      stroke: textHalo,
      offsetY: 14
    })
 });
```

Any suggestions how I could avoid that problem? My current Solution, is to use instead of a Style with an Image and a text to use two Styles one with the image and one with an SVG in that I replace the text. However that is rather a hack than a nice solution.

```
return [
new Style({
  image: new Icon({
    opacity: 1,
    src: imageSrc,
    anchor: [0.5, 1],
    scale: 0.6
  })
}),
new Style({
  image: new Icon({
    opacity: 1,
    src: imageText,
    anchor: [0.5, 0],
    scale: 0.8
  })
})
```

];

Comment: Could you provide relevant code?

Comment: Added a short update where I found that it crashed

Comment: What is "textHalo"? stroke is a class: stroke: new Stroke({color:'#FF0000'})

Comment: Ah sorry I fogot to replace that const textHalo = new Stroke({ color: 'white', width: 4 });

Comment: Ok and how many features to you add?

Comment: At most maybe 200, but I manage to freeze it with even one feature. At initial startup the app works great, also the app is not always freezing. So I'm not 100% sure why it only happens after the 4-5 seconds period.